# Guice override NamedCache binding

Tags: playframework, guice, ehcache

I am using Play 2.6 and Play cache abstraction.

I have 2 caches configured in the application with names "x" and "y".

During testing, I want to override each of these caches with my fake cache implementation.

The cache are annotated with `@NamedCache("X") val cache: AsyncCacheApi` or `@NamedCache("Y") val cache: AsyncCacheApi` but I cannot seem to override them in the module:

> ```
>     class FakeCacheModule extends AbstractModule {
>       override def configure(): Unit = {
>         bind(classOf[AsyncCacheApi]).annotatedWith(Names.named("X")).toInstance(new FakeCache)
>         bind(classOf[AsyncCacheApi]).toInstance(new FakeCache)
>         bind(classOf[AsyncCacheApi]).annotatedWith(Names.named("Y")).toInstance(new FakeCache)
>       }
>     }
> ```

None of these binding work.

Answer (score 0):

`Names.named("")` returns an instance of `com.google.inject.name.Named` but the cache binding is annotated with `play.cache.NamedCache`.

The implementation of `Names.named()` is:

```
public static Named named(String name) {
    return new NamedImpl(name);
}
```

and respectively you can get a working binding for the `NamedCache` annotation by using an instance of `NamedCacheImpl`, which implements `NamedCache`. Therefore a working solution would be

```
class FakeCacheModule extends AbstractModule {
    override def configure(): Unit = {
        bind(classOf[AsyncCacheApi]).annotatedWith(new NamedCacheImpl("X")).toInstance(new FakeCache)
        bind(classOf[AsyncCacheApi]).toInstance(new FakeCache)
        bind(classOf[AsyncCacheApi]).annotatedWith(new NamedCacheImpl("Y")).toInstance(new FakeCache)
  }
}
```